# Fundamental question about probability theory: Does $P(A\cap B)$ mean the probability of $A$ and $B$ occurring?

Tags: probability, notation

Does $P(A\cap B)$ mean the probability of $A$ and $B$ occurring and moreover what is the interpretation of $P(A\cup B)$ in terms of events? Sorry for the silly question but I need to make sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: Yes, it means $A$ and $B$ occurring. As to $A\cup B$, it means o,e of them (at least) occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $A \cap B$ means "both $A$ and $B$ occur," while $A \cup B$ means "either $A$ or $B$ (or both) occur."